# merging multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data frame like this one:

```
dataf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'C': ['c', 'c',np.nan]})


get_dummies(df):

   A_a     A_b     B_a     B_b     B_c    C_c
0  1       0       0       1       0      1
1  0       1       1       0       0      1
2  1       0       0       0       1      0
```

I want all common attributes of dataframe to be in one column. Here for attribute 'a' we have two columns i.e. A_a & B_a. I want that in one column with name 'a' and values as UNION of A_a & B_a. And it should be applicable to all similar attributes. It should look like:

```
   a       b      c 
0  1       1      1  
1  1       1      1  
2  1       0      1
```

In original, I have hundreds of thousands of attributes in million+ rows. Therefore a generic formula will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters `prefix` and `prefix_sep` to [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `columns` with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

dataf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'C': ['c', 'c',np.nan]})
print dataf
   A  B    C
0  a  b    c
1  b  a    c
2  a  c  NaN

df = pd.get_dummies(dataf, prefix="", prefix_sep="")
print df
   a  b  a  b  c  c
0  1  0  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0  0  1  0

print df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  0  1
```

EDIT by [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852050/merging-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe#comment59370339_35852332), thank you John Galt:

If values are `lenght = 1` (as in sample):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(dataf)
print df
   A_a  A_b  B_a  B_b  B_c  C_c
0    1    0    0    1    0    1
1    0    1    1    0    0    1
2    1    0    0    0    1    0

print df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1:], axis=1).any().astype(int)
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  0  1
```

Comment: Without using `prefix="", prefix_sep=""` you could do, `df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1:], axis=1).sum()` perhaps and for better readability, `.any().astype(int)` -- so that union doesn't exceed 1 ?

Comment: You are right, but if change values in `df`, it doesnt work.

Comment: You've a point there. I'm bit edgy with multiple columns having same name.

Comment: @JohnGalt - why do you use `any()` ? Thanks for comment.

Comment: `any` will return `True` when atleast one of the elements is True. I'm expecting output either 1 or 0. So, `any()` is safe that way.

Comment: I try `any`, but it creates `Series`. Do I miss something?

Comment: Strange, `df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1:], axis=1).any().astype(int)` works fine for me on `pd.__version__ == '0.17.1'`

Comment: I dont omit `sum`, so it doest work for me. There was problem.

Comment: you could also use `.max()`

Comment: @jezrael your solution works for me when data frame is small. Suggestion by John Galt did not work. But when I have a data frame of shape (303354, 99) I am getting memory error at first step itself: dummyX11 = pd.get_dummies(X11, prefix="", prefix_sep=""). I had another option which I had not mentioned and it worked for smaller data frame. I took unique values (3553 in total) from data frame and then ran: for x in values:
    dataf[x] = dataf.isin([x]).any(1).astype(int). This is also throwing memory error. I am running this code on server which has 16 GB memory. Any idea to optimize this?